# jQuery datepicker working in front end but not wordpress admin dash

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I have the current code for enqueuing the jQuery Date Picker:

```
function register_my_scripts()
{
    wp_register_script('scripts', plugins_url('/js/scripts.js', __FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
}

function register_my_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('e2b-admin-ui-css','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css',false,"1.9.0",false);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_my_scripts');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_my_styles');
```

the jQuery function which is inside scripts.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'D, m/d/yy'
    });
});
```

and the html field:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker"/>
```

This code work fine on the front end but for some reason doesn't do anything on the back end. I only need it to work on the backend.

What's going on here?

Comment: Are you sure you've included the scripts.js in the back end?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you need to serve your scripts on `admin_enqueue_scripts` instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','register_my_scripts');
```

See [this link](http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-date-picker-to-wordpress-admin) for more details

Comment: Tried this but still only working in the front end :/